# Using a record set to generate new tables in ACCESS

Tags: ms-access

I am using an ACCESS database to generate reports on a relatively big dataset. As I  don't want to wait eternally and also ACCESS has certain size limitations, I execute a complex sql query on my server.

Now I would like to use the result of this complex sql query inside ACCESS to do some final stuff and then display in a form.

I know how to connect ACCESS directly to database tables, I also know how to work from there. But here I have a gap: I have a SQL with some few thousand lines and receive the result as recordset. How to make ACCESS accepting this in it's own architecture?

```
Dim SQL As String
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

'SQL query
SQL = "  SELECT something quite complex and long"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "my great server"
conn.Open

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open SQL, conn
'--- here is my personal gap ---
conn.Close
```

Comment: What do you mean? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I execute a complex command on the SQL server. This command is too big for ACCESS. The resultset is not too big for ACCESS. I would like to reuse this resultset for display and reporting purposes in ACCESS.

Comment: What do you mean with _This command is too big for ACCESS_? What do you mean with _reuse this resultset_? Be specific. I can show you how to bind a recordset to a form or report, if that's your question, but it doesn't seem to be

Comment: "Too big for Access" means the 2GB border. "Reuse this resultset" is, my customer wants to use his old-well known-Access surface without change, so i want to implement it there.

Comment: _my customer wants to use his old-well known-Access surface without change_ is still not very specific in my opinion. Do you want it available in a form, a report, a query? Which one is difficult for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a passthru query (or a normal one) with your complex request and save it
2. create a Make Table Access query that basically contains
   `select * from myComplexPTQ into myLocalTable`
3. done

If you use *normal* query rather than *passthru*, and you find it slow, I suggest you give a look at http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html

Comment: That pass through query ability was what i was searching for. Thanks a lot, it works very well.

Comment: How? I am fairly new to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

If your "very complex" SQL code is a stored procedure - you can execute that and return results from it using a pass through query. See here [Two ways to execute a Stored procedure in VBA, Which one is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328669/two-ways-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-in-vba-which-one-is-better)

If it's a View you can simply link to the view, just like a table.

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look into pass through queries. We have both, scheduled stored procedures (whose result i can easily access like a view or a table); but also sql commands with more than 5000 lines, that are not yet stored procedures and will likely never be. It's those second kind of requests i am talking about. They were running in Access, like, 30 minutes. In SQL, after optimizing, they run in roughly 2 minutes, which is ok for the customer.

Comment: 5000 lines of SQL is an application... Had you considered saving those as a SP? Or  depending on the data  using them to create temporary results tables you can link to, if it's not "live" data?